# What's the difference between killstreak, specialized killstreak, and professional killstreak weapons?

Tags: team-fortress-2, terminology

I've been playing a fair bit of the new MVM tours, and have seen killstreak kits, specialized killstreak fabricators, and a couple professional killstreak fabricators.

Based on the update notes, killstreak weapons track the number of kills in the same life you get with that weapon. What's the difference between standard killstreak, specialized, and professional?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is taken directly from the [wiki](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/):

## Standard

> ...simply add[s] a HUD kill counter

## Specialized

> ...adds a kill counter as well as a colored sheen that intensifies as streaks increase

## Professional

> ...in addition to adding a kill counter and colored sheen, also causes the weapon to add a particle effect to the user's eyes (similar to the Eyelander) that intensifies with kills

**Source**: [1](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Killstreak_Kit_Fabricator) | [2](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Killstreak)